# Artifacts on writing opengl buffer to a video

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, video

I am using `glReadPixels` to read from OpenGL context and eventually write it to a video file using openCV video writer.

```
    screenshot = glReadPixels(0,0,w,h,GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    cv_image = cv2.cv.CreateImage((w,h), cv2.cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv2.cv.SetData(cv_image, screenshot)
    cv2.cv.Flip(cv_image)
    cv2.cv.SaveImage("temp.jpg", cv_image)
    cv2.cv.WriteFrame(video, cv_image)
```

The video rendered shows the artifacts as in the image below. I saved all the frames(cv_image variable above) to the disk and none of them had any artifacts. It seems WriteFrame is causing some trouble here.
Please help me figure out the problem.

[image]

Comment: not, that it will make any difference, but *get rid of the deprecated cv2.cv* . next opencv will only support cv2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to lossless compression schemes like PNG (for images) or Huffyuv (for video).

Comment: I tried Huffyuv which solves the issue but resulting video file size is getting too big(in Gigabytes). Replacing my current compression scheme with MPEG-4.3 codec also solves the artifacts problem while keeping the file size in control.